# How to send protocol-buffers messages to a websocket API using Python?

Tags: python, api, websocket, protocol-buffers

I want to get data from a websocket API which is using .proto messages to communicate between server and client, and all this using python.

The thing is that I have no idea about how all this is working. Because I must communicate with this server via Python, I've been able to generate _pb2.py files from .proto files with protoc, and this is all I've been able to do so far.

Now, I really don't understand what i am supposed to do with my generated .py file in order to send a message to the server from python and to get a response from it.

Comment: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Thanks. the address I try to reach starts by wss and not http, and it appears that "request" can't deal with this kind of addresses